# Ubuntu does not start from CD

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, cd

Installed 11.10, I tried to start 12.04 from CD but just got the purple screen with color changing dots and then name Ubuntu. 
CD drive control LED shows 2 seconds with 5 seconds pause... Drive constantly starts and stops. And, by the way, the hard disk Led indicates some data transfer, what, as far as I understand should not happen while starting ubuntu from CD

Comment: Is the disk scratched in any way? Drives will start and stop often if the disk can't be read. It will also read the hard disks to get partition info and help prepare the partitions for mounting from the live CD image,

Comment: What sort of hardware are you using? I've experience intensely long loading times for the Live CD or pretty old pretty old computers. How long did you wait before giving up?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that in the past with ubuntu 10.10 on a couple of computers.  The solution for me was to use the alternate installation cd instead.  It worked like a champ.